# How to apply change to some lines from many files in AIX?

Tags: awk, sed, aix

I've 85 files with this type of lines :

```
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;128.00;106.54;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;180.79;/usr/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;384.00;191.13;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.37;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;3200.00;2679.36;/var/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.07;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;64.00;62.67;/etc/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;1664.00;1163.33;/opt
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;146.13;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;952.90;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;10353.91;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;229.92;/home
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;556.73;/opt
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;180.79;/usr/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;384.00;190.90;/var
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;255.37;/var/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;128.00;127.63;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;76.86;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;1682.93;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;145.66;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;952.90;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;10421.72;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;138.8;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;5248.00;4230.34;/usr
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;2560.00;499.37;/var
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;3584.00;67.79;/tmp
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;25.9;/home
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;467.27;/opt
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;384.00;0.38;/usr/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;21.36;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;512.00;216.84;/opt/
```

The output needed :

```
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;128.00;21.46;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;75.21;/usr/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;384.00;192.87;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;0.63;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;3200.00;520.64;/var/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;0.93;/var/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;64.00;1.33;/etc/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;1664.00;500.67;/opt
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;109.87;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;1223.1;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;12430.1;/opt/
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;256.00;2.36;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;26.08;/home
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;467.27;/opt
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;75.21;/usr/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;384.00;193.1;/var
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;0.63;/var/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;128.00;0.37;/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;179.14;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;493.07;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;110.34;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;2176.00;1223.1;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;22784.00;12362.3;/opt/
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;2.36;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;138.8;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;5248.00;4230.34;/usr
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;2560.00;499.37;/var
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;3584.00;67.79;/tmp
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;25.9;/home
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;1024.00;467.27;/opt
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;384.00;0.38;/usr/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;256.00;21.36;/
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xx;512.00;216.84;/opt/
```

I try to do that ( I grep "2019-10" because there is the date in the filename and I'm interested only by the files with "2019-10" in the filename ):

```
for i in $(ls *.txt | grep "2019-10")
do 
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '/2019-10-29-12-00/{$4=$3-$4;} 1' $i > BACK-$i
done
```

But it doesn't works... And I don't know why ! Could you show me how to do that ?

Comment: *"But it doesn't works"* is not a good problem statement. Many folks don't have access to AIX, so they will never know how it does not work. AIX is like the BSDs and Solaris. They have some anemic Posixy tools. Don't use the GNU extensions on those boxes. Or, scp the files to a Linux box to use the GNU extensions. You can probably do it all with awk. No need for sed.

Comment: Can't ```for i in $(ls *.txt | grep "2019-10")``` be replaced by ```for i in *2019-10*.txt```? There is no need to exec an external program (two in this case) for that. Also there is no need to use ```sed```. You can do it all using just ```awk```.

Comment: The awk line looks like it should work. How does it not work? [It works on repl bash](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/AlarmedScientificEmbeds) Maybe you are confused about `ls *.txt | grep "2019-10"` - what do you think `ls *.txt | grep "2019-10"` does?

Comment: Hello, I've edited my post to be more clear

Comment: Specify what exactly does not work. I copied your awk line and run against the input you specified. I got the output with substracted the columns, properly. What does not work? No files are generated? Your pc get's on fire and fire brigade starts coming through the window? What exactly happens?

Comment: On your repl, I see that only the lines with "2019-10-29-12-00" as pattern are changed. But I want that this change be applied to the first line of my file ( 2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;128.00;106.54;/var/ ) at the last line of the file including the pattern 2019-10-29-12-00 (2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/ )

Comment: The output wanted has more lines than the input. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I've edited my post with only my input and the ouput wanted. 
Both are 33 lines.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clearly and simply state your requirements. You stand the best chance of getting help if we don't have to try to figure out what it is you're trying to do from large sample input/output (why can't you show us with 5 or 6 lines pf input/output instead of 33), a script that **doesn't** do whatever it is you wat to do, and a bunch of hints spread out across multiple comments.

Answer (score 1):

This script can do the work:

```
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '/2019-10-29-12-00/{$4=$3-$4; print} '
```

I do not know why this `1` at the end do not want to work in your case

Comment: `1`should work if you skip negation. `awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '! /2019-10-29-12-00/{next}{$4=$3-$4}1' file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in *2019-10*.txt; do
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}/2019-10-29-(06|12)-00/{$4=$3-$4}1' "${i}" >"BACK-${i}"
done
```

The code above will match lines with `2019-10-29-` followed by `06-00` OR `12-00`, as you have in the sample output.

If you need to match all lines within the range from `06-00` to `12-000`, use the script below:

```
 for i in *2019-10*.txt; do
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}/2019-10-29-(0[6-9]|1[0-2])-00/{$4=$3-$4}1' "${i}" >"BACK-${i}"
done
```

I hope it now does what you want.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help !

Your loop applies the change only on the lines including the "2019-10-29-12-00" as pattern. And for that, it works great. But I would like to apply this loop to the first line of the file at, to the last file with 2019-10-29-12-00 as pattern ( so from 2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xx;128.00;106.54;/var/ to 2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xx;256.00;253.64;/ ).

Comment: Just to clarify: do you always want the first line and all the pattern matching lines to be changed? If that is what you want the change is trivial.

Comment: Now I see what you want and the script above does that. If I got it right, you want all entries on ```2019-10-29``` ```06:00``` and ```12:00``` included, right? If you need that to be a time range, let me know and I will adjust the regex.